# Accessing variables for Jenkins Builds

Tags: git, jenkins

I have 3 applications that are dependent on each other. When developing each application can be on a different branch, but to test one of these applications I have to be able to set all the branches correctly.

I have each application set up on a job to Poll it's relevant SCM.

When running the Jenkins build how could I pass the branches required as variables so that they can be used by Jenkins?

Hope this makes sense, any questions then please ask

Thanks

Comment: You should be using submodules.

Comment: thanks, but would you care to explain a little further please ?

Comment: When using submodules, the main project keeps a reference to a specific commit in the subproject, so you wouldn't have to pass the branch names as parameters, since the information about which commit to use is already in the main project.

Comment: But anyway, for jenkins, just tick _"this build is parameterized"_ in configuration, introduce a variable for each branch name that you need, and then use those in the _"Branches to build"_ section.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven project, you could also introduce profile tags in your **pom.xml** of all applications and apparently use those profile in your build jobs in Jenkins.

Hope this helps.